# Dell R700 RAID card for R210, will it work/fit?

Tags: dell-poweredge, hardware-raid, h700

Looking to improve output on VMware.

Will Dell F2WGY Perc H700 Modular work in a R210 II server?

Comment: "Looking to improve output on VMware." - That statement makes absolutely no sense. How about providing some context and detail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Looking to improve output on VMware.

Aren't we all?

Now, on to your actual question:

> Will Dell F2WGY Perc H700 Modular work in a R210 II server?

Why not ask Dell?

Or, look at the Controller matrix [chart](http://www.dell.com/learn/us/en/04/campaigns/dell-raid-controllers). Or review the [technical guide](http://www.dell.com/downloads/global/products/pvaul/en/perc-technical-guidebook.pdf) for the actual controller you think might work. Or, review the [technical guide](http://i.dell.com/sites/doccontent/shared-content/data-sheets/en/Documents/r-210-2-technical-guide.pdf) or [spec sheet](http://i.dell.com/sites/doccontent/shared-content/data-sheets/en/Documents/Dell_PowerEdge_R210II_Spec_Sheet.pdf) for the server itself which should list any supported and compatible cards for your specific server.

On a side note, please take a little time to do some looking prior to asking here.

To answer your specific question on will it work. The answer is No, it will not work. The only supported cards according to the server's technical guide are:

- PERC S100 (software RAID)
- PERC S300 (software RAID)
- PERC H200
- PERC H800

But spinning back - what is the real issue you are seeing and how have you determined the controller will solve your problem?